# How do I execute a complex "find" linux shell command in python

Tags: python, linux

I need to execute the following command:

```
find PATH -type f -exec du -h --all {} +
```

Here's my attempt to do this:

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.Popen(["find", PATH, "-type", "f", "-exec", "du", "-h", "--all", "{}", "+"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print(result)
```

And as a result I get some rubbish. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need `shell=True`

Comment: What rubbish are you getting?

Comment: @Barmar Well the script is supposed to list all the files in a certain directory. But it listed some files that it was not supposed to list. But I followed your advice and removed `shell=True` and now it works as expected!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only use `shell=True` when the first argument to `Popen()` is a string that should be parsed by the shell. If it's an array, you've already done the necessary parsing, and shouldn't use `shell=True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import commands

commands = r'''find PATH -type f -exec du -h --all {} +'''
result = commands.getstatusoutput(command)[0]
print("{}".format(result))
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: commands module is build over os.open(), this takes system command as a normal string and return a tuple containing any output generated by the command and, optionally, the exit status. First item in a tuple is always a status code of the commands run and item at index 1 is always an out generated by the command. However, if you're using python 2.6 above or 3.x, then this module doesn't work
More details https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html